# Firebase rules are not applied as supposed to

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having weird behaviors with my Firebase Firestore Rules recently.
I am protecting a collection like so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function getRoles() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role;
    }
    function isAdmin() {
      return 'admin' in getRoles();
    }
    match /registrationsRequests/{document} {
      allow create: if true;
      allow read, update, delete: if false;
    }
    match /users/{document} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == document || isAdmin();
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == document || isAdmin();
    }   
  }
}
```

After I log in (and I check if the user is available with its UID), I fetch the user. But I receive the following error (both checks should return true => isAdmin() and document)

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

@edit: The query used

```
const usrDoc = await this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).ref.get()
```

Comment: Rules mean nothing without the queries being used - please add the into the post.

Comment: Sure @LeadDreamer, I added it in the post.

Comment: hm.  I would have written ```const usrDoc = await this.db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get()``` - ```.get()``` is a method of the DocumentReference returned by ```.doc()``` - I'm also not sure of the precedence of operators in rules, so I would have written ```allow read, write: if (request.auth.uid == document) || isAdmin();```  have you verified in console the values of those variables - or, indeed, the ```.doc().ref.path``` ?